# Application crashes when changing to landscape mode

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

If I start application in landscape mode it runs fine, but if I 
change the mode from landscape or profile it crashes.
can anyone see some obvious errors in my code?
I have tried to set only portrait mode in manifest but no success with that.

code:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClick {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_timeline, new TimeLineFragment());
    transaction.commit();

}

@Override
public void OnClickListener(Status status) {

    if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_detailedtweet) != null) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("StatusData", status);
        DetailTweetFragments detailTweetFragment = new DetailTweetFragments();
        detailTweetFragment.SetStatus(status);
        detailTweetFragment.setArguments(bundle);


        FragmentTransaction trancationTableView = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trancationTableView.replace(R.id.fragment_detailedtweet, detailTweetFragment);
        trancationTableView.commit();

    } else {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("StatusData", status);
        DetailTweetFragments detailTweetFragment = new DetailTweetFragments();
        detailTweetFragment.SetStatus(status);
        detailTweetFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentTransaction trancationTableView = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trancationTableView.replace(R.id.fragment_timeline, detailTweetFragment);
        trancationTableView.addToBackStack(null);
        trancationTableView.commit();
    }

}


@Override
public void OnMakeTweet() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TwitterUpdateActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
public void OnProfile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TwitterProfileActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
}

    public class TimeLineAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Status>{

private Activity activityContext;
public TimeLineAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.status_item);
    activityContext = (Activity) context;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    Status status = this.getItem(position);

    View view = activityContext.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.status_item, null);

    TextView tweetText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tweet_from_timeLine);
    tweetText.setText(status.getText());

    TextView profileName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_name_status);
    profileName.setText(status.getUser().getName());

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.left_layout);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());

    layout.addView(imageView);

    public class TimeLineFragment extends Fragment {

Button timeLine_button;
Button makeTweet_button;
Button profile_button;
TimeLineAdapter adapter; 
OnClick onClickListener;


public ResponseList<twitter4j.Status> statuses;

public interface OnClick {
    public void OnClickListener(Status status);

    public void OnMakeTweet();
    public void OnProfile();
}



@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        onClickListener = (OnClick) activity;
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    onClickListener = null;

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timeline, null);


    ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.tweet_list);


    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View praent, int position,
                long id) {
            onClickListener.OnClickListener(statuses.get(position));

        }
    });


    makeTweet_button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.makeTweet_button);
    makeTweet_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickListener.OnMakeTweet();
        }
    });

    profile_button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_button);
    profile_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickListener.OnProfile();
        }
    });

    new LoadTmeLine().execute();

    return view; 

}




private class LoadTmeLine extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Twitter twitter = TwitterLogInActivity.twitter;
        try {
            statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
        } catch (TwitterException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        adapter = new TimeLineAdapter(getActivity());
        for(twitter4j.Status status : statuses) {
            adapter.add(status);
        }

        ListView list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tweet_list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

EXCEPTION:

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:104)
  .adapters.TimeLineAdapter.<init>(TimeLineAdapter.java:31)
  .fragments.TimeLineFragment$LoadTmeLine.onPostExecute(TimeLineFragment.java:132)
  .fragments.TimeLineFragment$LoadTmeLine.onPostExecute(TimeLineFragment.java:1)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631) 
  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MANIFEST:

```
    application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="twitter.TwitterLogInActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="twitter.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: What is the 132th line of your `TimeLineFragment.java` file?

Comment: Add your manifest activity part

Comment: nKn - adapter = new TimeLineAdapter(getActivity()); is the 132th line

Comment: I don't understand your code. Your `MainActivity` implements `OnClick` - what is that? Also you have an overridden method of `public void OnClickListener(Status status)` - that isn't a method of `Activity`. You're also overriding other methods like `onMakeTweet` and `OnProfile` in your `Activity`. None of this makes sense and your code shouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

When the orientation changes, the activity is killed and recreated. You typically get null pointers like this when you are not saving state correctly. As for forcing the app to portrait mode. This should do it.

```
<activity
     android:name=".MyActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: The attribute `android:configChanges="orientation"` is not needed to force a particular orientation. It's used to specify the code will override `onConfigurationChanged(...)` and that will be used to handle various things specific to the `Activity`.

Comment: @Nick Pontiff - saving state? can you give me an exampel...(this is my first andriod app)

android:screenOrientation="portrait" - works on phone not tablet..

Answer (score 0):

If you have different folders for layouts (`layout-land` for landscape, and `layout` for normal),  then make sure both of them has the same views. Sometimes I happened to add a new view to the normal layout, but forgot to add it too into the landscape layout